# SQL Server cursor update

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I've got 2 questions about cursors:

1. Whats the fastest cursor for updates? Is it `DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY` ?
2. Do I need to select the in the cursor select clause primary key to update rows using cursor?

   ```
   UPDATE [myTable]
   SET [somecolumn] = 1
   WHERE CURRENT OF db_cursor
   ```

   `[somecolumn]` is not the Primary Key.

Comment: To be frank but I doubt you'll see much performance difference either way - especially compared to thinking another non-cursor direction, which is usually the advisable approach.
Is there a reason why you want to use cursor?

Comment: yes, I have a quite big database (few milion rows) and I can't lock them all. Curosr update locks the current row

Comment: Does every single row need to be updated or just a small portion of the few million? (a few million rows is not a big database in my opinion, I have 80M rows and I consider mine medium-sized.)

Comment: It looks like an important word is missing from your question #2 -- "Do I need to select the `something` in the cursor...", where I'll guess you surrounded "something" with special characters.  Edit your question, and put `something` back in, but this time, either:  (1) surround it all with the back-quote ("back-apostrophe"? on many keyboards, it's the same key where the tilde `~` appears... on the key to the left of the number `1`)... on StackOverflow, you can keep *any* special character, if you surround it in back-quotes, or (2) simply drop the special characters around that "something".